# JqGrid - treeGrid. Can't addChildNode properly

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with treeGrid option.

when I try to add child nodes:

```
grid.addChildNode('1', null, { id2: 1, groupName: 'a', loaded: true, isLeaf: false, expanded: false, level: 0 });

grid.addChildNode('2', '1', { id2: 2, groupName: 'a/b', loaded: true, isLeaf: false, expanded: false, level: 1 });

grid.addChildNode('3', '2', { id2: 3, groupName: 'a/b/c', loaded: true, isLeaf: false, expanded: false, level: 2 });

grid.addChildNode('7', '2', { id2: 7, groupName: 'a/b/d', loaded: true, isLeaf: false, expanded: false, level: 2 });

grid.addChildNode('10', '3', { id2: 10, groupName: 'a/b/c/e', loaded: true, isLeaf: false, expanded: false, level: 3 });

grid.addChildNode('11', '1', { id2: 11, groupName: 'a/f', loaded: true, isLeaf: false, expanded: false, level: 1 });
```

I have got result like this : 
[see image](http://www.imagebanana.com/view/tgatgmas/capture.JPG)

This is not good result because 'a/b/d' should be child of node 'a/b'. What is wrong with this example ?